# Selective left join in r

Tags: r, sqldf, fuzzyjoin

I want to selectively left join two dataframes based on a joint column and the condition of rows.

I saw some similar posts using fuzzyjoin and sqldf, but the previous examples I found are not exactly like mine.

Example dfs:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = c("1", "2", "3"),
              zipcode = c("11111", "44444", "33333"),
              exp.id = c("0", "0", "1"))
df2 <- data_frame(zipcode = c("11111", "22222", "33333", "44444", "55555"),
              pct = c("0.1", "0.5", "0.9", "0.7", "0.8"))
```

Basically, I want to join the "pct" column in df2 to df1 by zipcode but only join where "exp.id" = "0"

The outcome I expect should look like this:

```
  id    zipcode exp.id pct  
 <chr> <chr>   <chr>  <chr>
1 1     11111   0      0.1  
2 2     44444   0      0.7  
3 3     33333   1      NA
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** This left joins `df1` with `df2` on `zipcode` but only joins rows for which `exp.id` is 0.  For other rows `pct` is NA as in the expected result shown in the question.  Note that dot is an SQL operator so we surround `exp.id` with square brackets to escape the name.

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select a.id, a.zipcode, b.pct
  from df1 a 
  left join df2 b on a.zipcode = b.zipcode and [exp.id] = 0")
##   id zipcode  pct
## 1  1   11111  0.1
## 2  2   44444  0.7
## 3  3   33333 <NA>
```

**2)** This is like (1) but returns only the `exp.id` rows that are zero.  This is different than what is asked for in the question but a comment suggested that it is of interest.

The difference between the code here and (1) illustrate the subtle difference between including a condition in `on` and in `where`.  Because we have a simple condition in this case we can use the `using` clause instead of `on`.  `using` results in a single `zipcode` so we don't need to distinguish between `a.zipcode` and `b.zipcode`.

```
sqldf("select a.id, zipcode, b.pct
  from df1 a left join df2 b using(zipcode)
  where [exp.id] = 0")
##   id zipcode pct
## 1  1   11111 0.1
## 2  2   44444 0.7
```

Note that the SQL engine internally creates a query plan to optimize the calculation while maintaining the same output.  It does not necessarily perform the operations in the order written, i.e. it does not necessarily perform the join and then reduce the result but may reduce df1 first to improve performance as that gives the same result.  We display information on the query plan below and we see that, indeed, it scans `df1` first.

```
sqldf("explain query plan select a.id, zipcode, b.pct
      from df1 a left join df2 b using(zipcode)
      where [exp.id] = 0")
##   id parent notused                                                           detail
## 1  3      0       0                                              SCAN TABLE df1 AS a
## 2 16      0       0 SEARCH TABLE df2 AS b USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (zipcode=?)
```

Answer (score 2):

Join the data and turn the `pct` value to `NA` where `exp.id != 0`.

```
library(dplyr)

res <- df1 %>%
        left_join(df2, by = 'zipcode') %>%
        mutate(pct = replace(pct, exp.id != 0, NA))

res

#  id zipcode exp.id  pct
#1  1   11111      0  0.1
#2  2   44444      0  0.7
#3  3   33333      1 <NA>
```

In base R -

```
res <- transform(merge(df1, df2, by = 'zipcode', all.x = TRUE), 
                 pct = replace(pct, exp.id != 0, NA))
```

---

Also you can join only those values where `exp.id = 0`.

```
df1 %>%
  filter(exp.id == 0) %>%
  left_join(df2, by = 'zipcode') %>%
  right_join(df1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Actually, I have a larger number of exp.id that i dont need to join the pct. I wonder if there is any way I could only get exp.id = 0 joined instead of turning the others to NA.

Comment: I have edited the answer to show that but you can also ignore multiple value in `exp.id` using `%in%`. For eg - `vals <- c(0, 2, 3, 4)` and use `replace(pct, exp.id !%in% vals, NA)` in first answer whereas `filter(exp.id %in% vals)` in the second one.